# Attached an eventhandler with an If statement

Tags: php, jquery, logic

I am loading a file into a div, and then trying to force all links in that file to load within the div, as they would otherwise bring the browser to a new page.

I cannot understand why this works (user will navigate through webpage in only the #login div):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#login').load("indexLogin.php",function(){

                    $('#login').on("click", 'a', function(event){
                        var url = $(this).attr('href');
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#login').load(url);
                    });
                });
            });
```

But this does not (every single link is treated as a dropdown);

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#login').load("indexLogin.php",function(){

                    $('#login').on("click", 'a', function(event){
                        var url = $(this).attr('href');
                        if (url == "#" || " "){
                            console.log("dropdown");
                            return;     
                        }else{
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $('#login').load(url);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

I thought the logic is:
1. Attach the handler click to all 'a' with a callback
2. Callback runs, sets var, checks var, and performs result

Instead it seems to be saying: if ANY 'a' are of "#" or "" then return. Why?

Comment: That's an error, you can't do that in an if statement, it should be `if (url == "#" || url == " "){`

Answer (score 2):

That's because your `if` statement's signature is wrong, `url == "#" || " "` this will always evaluates to `true`.

Try,

```
if (url == "#" || url == " "){
```